# .NET CORE(on windows), DataReceived called frequency of one serialPort effected by other serialPort

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I have a .NET CORE 2.1 console application that is communicating with 2 devices which are both `half-duplex` via 2 comPort (rs232).

- the device A on COM1, baud rate 9600, my app polling it every 200ms, and get response in 50ms.
- the device B on COM2, baud rate 1200, my app receive its poll every 400ms, and responding it in 50ms.

the code for two comPort are **totally separated**, no share variable, no reference and etc.

For device A:

```
private ConcurrentQueue<object> outgoingMessageQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<object>();
this.comPort1.DataReceived += (a,b)=>{
    while (this.comPort1.BytesToRead > 0){
        var b = this.comPort.ReadByte();
        buffer.Add((byte)b);
    };
    if(CheckIsFullMessage(buffer))
    {//fire event for consume}

};
ThreadPool.QueueWorkerThread((_)=>{
while(true){
    Thread.Sleep(200); 
    if (this.outgoingMessageQueue.TryDequeue(out object pendingForWrite))
    {this.comPort1.Write(pendingForWrite); }
    else
        this.comPort1.Write(new PollMsg());
}};
//business logic, queue a request at any time.
this.outgoingMessageQueue.Add(new requestMessage());
```

For device B:

```
this.comPort2.DataReceived += (a,b)=>{
    while (this.comPort2.BytesToRead > 0){
        var b = this.comPort.ReadByte();
        buffer.Add((byte)b);
    };
    if(CheckIsFullMessage(buffer))
    {
      //trigger business logic, consume the buffer and construct a response.
      //this.comPort2.Write(response,0,response.length); 
    }       
};
```

I noticed a thing, that if I turned on device B, the `DataReceived` for **device A** (comPort1) will be **randomly** delayed to be called(from ms to seconds), during the delay period, device A's 200ms polling is never stoped, so I'll suddenly get huge data from device A at one `DataReceived`.

Could anyone help, why these two comPorts affected each other?

-----more test----

I've did a test that connect 3 device A in 3 comPort into app, they works good, no `DataReceived` delayed.

Comment: That is possible, DataReceived is fired on a threadpool thread.  So if you have too many of them running then it can take a while to get it serviced.  Thread.Sleep() and while(true) are drastically practices on a tp thread so start there first, use a Thread.

Comment: Yup. Look into tweaking the `ReceivedBytesThreshold` to potentially throttle the event frequency. [Some success reported here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d5b07e74-6277-428f-b60f-3049df9d69af/c-problem-with-multiple-serialdatarecieved-event-handlers?forum=netfxbcl). If you google for `DataReceived` problems, it seems to be a common sore point to many people.

Comment: I forgot to mention, "too much data" is a good thing, not a bad thing.  It is guaranteed to happen sooner or later.  Think a garbage collection or a very busy machine.  So it must never be a problem, fix that first.  And you probably need to address `//fire buffer full event`.  It is not full, not nearly.  Getting only 1 or 2 bytes is normal.  Buffering until you got the full response of the device is highly advisable.

Comment: @HansPassant 1. you suggest like this `new Thread(() => { while (true) Thread.Sleep(200);/* dequeue and send */ }).Start();`, correct? what is the good vs mine.      2. If I set `ThreadPool.SetMin(worker, io)` to higher, does it help to stable the `onDataReceived`?

Comment: @NPras Length of a full msg for device 1 varied from 3 to 14, while it's 4 to 15 for device 2, and seems set that `ReceivedBytesThreshold` will lower down the call frequency, correct? my expectation is to increase the frequency though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing and post from web, I confirmed this behavior on .NET CORE, that multiple `SerialPort` write&receive could delay the firing of the `DataReceived`, so rather than wait, I've added a code to **actively pull**

```
    public void Start()
    {
        this.comPort.DataReceived += (_,__)=>{this.PullPortDataBuffer();};
        //for very fast time accurate call(my app send&receive data every 200ms), use dedicated thread rather than timer.
        this.pullingSerialPortBufferLoop = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {                
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                this.PullPortDataBuffer();
            }
        });
        this.pullingSerialPortBufferLoop.Start();
    };
    var buffer = new List<byte>();
    private void PullPortDataBuffer()
    {
        if (0 == Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.onPullingComPortBuffer, 1, 0))
            try
            {

                while (this.comPort.BytesToRead > 0)
                {                        
                    this.buffer.Add((byte)b);
                }

                this.ConsumeBufferIfFull(this.buffer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {}
            finally
            {
                this.onPullingComPortBuffer = 0;
            }
        else
        {
            if (logger.IsDebugEnabled)
                logger.Debug(this.comPort.PortName + " concurrent enter Port_DataReceived");
        }
    }
```

from my testing, the issue is gone.